# Create Line with absolute position not align with text center

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

When I use 'text-center' I do not have text and line are vertical alignment. Here is js fiddle.
I want like this: [image]

https://jsfiddle.net/dungvd/ey4fj6nv/2/.

test.html:

```
"<div>Question</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row  ">
        <div class="col-sm-6 mx-auto text-center">
                <h2 class="green-line">
                        Welcome to course bs2wp
                </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> "
```

test.css:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h2.green-line {
    position: relative;
}

h2.green-line:after {
    content: "";position: absolute;
    width: 65px;height: 5px;
    background: green;
    top: 0px;left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change CSS to `h2.green-line:after` `top:50%` & `transform:translatey(-50%);`

```
 h2.green-line {
    position: relative;
    display:inline;
}

h2.green-line:after {
    content: "";position: absolute;
    width: 65px;height: 5px;
    background: green;
    top: 0;left: 0px;

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/80zy4hc6/3/

Comment: sorry I want a result like picture I'v added into edit post. You can see then help me.Thank you

Comment: check Now https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/80zy4hc6/6/

Comment: Wow ! awesome.Thank you very muach  @Lalji Tadhani

Comment: If it helped out please mark the answer

Comment: But when i increase the length text to "Welcome to course edumall bs2wp" it not True

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/80zy4hc6/7/

Comment: :)) sorry Thanks